# Finding $a_n$ and $b_n$ of $f(x)= \begin{cases} \sin(2x), \text{ if } 0\le x\le\frac{\pi}{2} \\ 0, \text{ if } \frac{\pi}{2} \le x\le \pi \end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Finding $a_n$ and $b_n$ of the Fourier Series for:

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} \sin(2x), \text{ if } 0\le x\le \frac{\pi}{2} \\ 0, \text{ if } \frac{\pi}{2} \le x\le \pi \end{cases}$$

I know that:

$a_n = \frac{2}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\cos(nx)dx$ which I found to be:
$$a_n = \frac{2}{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(2x)\cos(nx)dx$$
$$=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(2x)\cos(nx)dx$$
$$ = \frac{-16\cos^2(\frac{\pi n}{4})}{\pi(n^2-4)}$$

$b_n=\frac{2}{b-a}\int_{a}^b{}f(x)\sin(nx)dx$ which I found to be:

$$ b_n =\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(2x)\sin(nx)dx$$
$$ = \frac{-8sin(\frac{\pi n}{2})}{\pi(n^2-4)}$$

Are my values for $a_n$ and $b_n$ correct? Also, how would I find $a_0$? Would it just be $a_0 = \frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(2x)dx$?

Comment: The way to derive the coefficients is by starting with the Fourier series $$f = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n} \cos \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) + b_{n} \sin \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \right)$$ and then multiplying both sides by $\cos(m \pi x/L)$ (similarly $\sin(m \pi x/L)$) and integrating over the domain $x \in [0, \pi]$ which yields the forms of $a_{n}, b_{n}$. Hopefully you can now determine what $a_{0}$ is.

Comment: You can simplify these results using the fact $n$ is an integer.